# Using rawquery to do an INNER JOIN in SQLite (AndroidStudio)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to do an inner join on two tables in sqllite, through android studio. I have tested my query in DB Browser for SQL Lite and it returns 4 rows (see below) but when run the query in android studio, it's not successful and my Log.d returns "size=0".

I have also tried String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " +  PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE + " INNER JOIN " + PLANT_TABLE + " ON " + PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE.PLANT_ID  + " = " + PLANT_TABLE.ID;
and

String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " +  PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE + " INNER JOIN " + PLANT_TABLE + " ON " + PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE.COLUMN_PLANTS_OWNED_PLANT_ID  + " = " + PLANT_TABLE.COLUMN_PLANT_ID;

[image: result showing successful query that returns rows]

```
public List<Plant> getOwnedPlants()
{
    List<Plant> ownedPlants = new ArrayList<>();
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM  PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE  INNER JOIN  PLANT_TABLE ON  PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE.PLANT_ID  = PLANT_TABLE.ID";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Plant currentPlant = new Plant();
            currentPlant.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            currentPlant.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            currentPlant.setScientific_Name(cursor.getString(2));
            currentPlant.setLight(cursor.getString(3));
            currentPlant.setWater(cursor.getString(4));
            currentPlant.setFertilizer(cursor.getString(5));
            currentPlant.setTemperature(cursor.getString(6));
            currentPlant.setHumidity(cursor.getString(7));
            currentPlant.setFlowering(cursor.getString(8));
            currentPlant.setPests(cursor.getString(9));
            currentPlant.setDiseases(cursor.getString(10));
            currentPlant.setSoil(cursor.getString(11));
            currentPlant.setPot_size(cursor.getString(12));
            currentPlant.setPruning(cursor.getString(13));
            currentPlant.setPropagation(cursor.getString(14));
            currentPlant.setPoisonous_plant_info(cursor.getString(15));

            ownedPlants.add(currentPlant);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    android.util.Log.d("INT", String.format("size = %d", ownedPlants.size()));
    return ownedPlants;
}
```

Here is the table setup, above getOwnedPlants() on the same page:

```
// PLANT_TABLE
    public static final String PLANT_TABLE = "PLANT_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_SCI_NAME = "SCIENTIFIC_NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_LIGHT = "LIGHT";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_WATER = "WATER";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_FERTILIZER = "FERTILIZER";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_TEMPERATURE = "TEMPERATURE";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_HUMIDITY = "HUMIDITY";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_FLOWERING = "FLOWERING";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_PESTS = "PESTS";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_DISEASES = "DISEASES";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_SOIL = "SOIL";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_POT_SIZE = "POT_SIZE";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_PRUNING = "PRUNING";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_PROPAGATION = "PROPAGATION";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANT_POISON = "POISONOUS_PLANT_INFO";

    // USER_TABLE - keeping this table in case we want to provide a more "personalized"
    //              experience by using the user's name
    public static final String USER_TABLE = "USER_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";

    // WISHLIST_TABLE
    public static final String WISHLIST_TABLE = "WISHLIST_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_WISHLIST_ID = "WISHLIST_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_WISHLIST_PLANT_ID = "PLANT_ID"; // references PLANT_TABLE

    // PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE
    public static final String PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE = "PLANTS_OWNED_TABLE";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANTS_OWNED_ID = "PLANTS_OWNED_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_PLANTS_OWNED_PLANT_ID = "PLANT_ID"; // references PLANT_TABLE
```

Any input is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Probably the database that you access with DB Browser for SQLite is not an exact copy of the database of your app.

Comment: @forpas that would make sense but when I edited the database in DB Browser, it created a new plant-journal.db file within the assets folder on android studio, and when I clicked "write changes" in DB Browser that file disappeared in android studio (which made me assume that the new changes had been written to the plant.db file)

Comment: Extract the db from the device/emulator and inspect it with DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: @forpas Yeah it appears to be the same database

Comment: Instead of logging the list's size, log the number of rows returned by the cursor: `cursor.getCount()`.

Comment: @forpas that also returned 0, so you were right in that it somehow wasn't working off the same db file. Cleaned and rebuilt the project, pushed everything to github, and restarted the emulator and now it's working properly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is a problem with your code. Join the tables in reverse order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224579/discussion-between-shagalabagala-and-forpas).